# Split string, get second half

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string, but grab the second half of the string...

```js
var str = "How, are, you, doing, today?";
var res = str.split(",", 3);

console.log(res);
```

Returns `"How,are,you."` How can I get `"doing,today?"`?

Perhaps `split()` isn't the best way? All I would like is to  do is essentially split the string in half and get both values as different variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` to get all values (by not passing a number to it), and then use `slice` to get values from index `3` to the end of the list of values:

```js
var str = "How, are, you, doing, today?";
var res = str.split(",").slice(3);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Per the question, I guess it is ... :/. Unless an edit is made and the question completely changes, as they sometimes do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what the length of your CSV string will be, you could:

```js
const get2ndHalf = (csv, del = ',') => {
  const arr = csv.split(del);
  return arr.slice(Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)).join(del).trim();
} 

console.log( get2ndHalf("How, are, you, doing, today?") )
console.log( get2ndHalf("This; one; is; a; tiny; bit; longer!", ";") ) // using delimiter ;
console.log( get2ndHalf("One") ) // Hummmm maybe rather Math.floor instead of math.ceil!
```

Or even better, to prevent empty results (like in the example above) use `Math.floor`

```js
const get2ndHalf = (csv, del = ',') => {
  const arr = csv.split(del);
  return arr.slice(Math.floor(arr.length / 2)).join(del).trim();
} 

console.log( get2ndHalf("How, are, you, doing, today?") )
console.log( get2ndHalf("This; one; is; a; tiny; bit; longer!", ";") ) // using delimiter ;
console.log( get2ndHalf("One") ) // Now this one is legit!
```